# How to randomly pick a string from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that consists of 10,000 randomly generated characters but in order to proceed in my project I need to create 100 strings of length 20 from the data set.

I was wondering how I would be able to code this in python so that it picks 100 patterns of length 20 from the string without the chosen strings overlapping no pattern being repeated.

This is my current code to generate the patterns, I am not the best programmer.

[Current string generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XQIM.png)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is off topic because SO is not a code writing service, if you want to get a proper answer you need to update your question with the code that you have tried so far and describe that what's the problem with it. Or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to show if you want to remove each chosen string from the possibilities or not. You also need to say if multiple values for a chosen index are allowed or if overlaps are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not show what you are doing with these and if repeats are or are not allowed, I will give a description of what you need to do.

1. get the size of the full data set.
2. generate a random number for starting index. make sure not to overrun the buffer (start index must be at least 20 characters before the end of the buffer
3. get the slice starting at the chosen index from the buffer and put in your list
4. delete the slice from the buffer.
5. loop for the required number of times
6. Now process your list.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and implement this and I will reply shortly